# perform rank on multiple columns in a data frame in one line of code

Tags: r

I have a "source" data frame that with data in 3 columns. I would like to rank the variables in each column and output into a new data frame.

This code works for one column. Can I write this formula to include other columns?

`SortedFundamentals1 <- as.data.frame(rank(EquityFundamentals$Forward.P.E))`

This works on one column, but can I put in the other columns and do them all at once? The ranking is independent for each column.

The other columns are: `FCF.Yield` and `Operating.Margin`

Comment: Try `library(dplyr); df1 %>% mutate_at(vars(Forward.P.E, FCF.Yield, Operating.Margin), rank)`

Comment: Thanks, akrun. Is there no way to modify the "as.data.frame" function to do that? I'm curious and I'm a total newbie and want to learn the various ways to modify that function's syntax...

Comment: code formatting and clean up language a bit

Answer (score 0):

This shroud work

```
SortedFundamentals1 = 
        as.data.frame( do.call(cbind, 
                               list(rank(EquityFundamentals$Forward.P.E),
                                    rank(EquityFundamentals$FCF.Yield),
                                    rank(EquityFundamentals$Operating.Margin))))
```